# Как изменить ширину колонок TreeWidget в Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer, qtreewidget

Хочу изменить ширину колонок `TreeWidget` в `Qt Designer`, но никак не найду параметр, который их меняет.

В предпросмотре их можно менять вручную, но хочется, чтобы они автоматом стояли нужного размера. Как это реализовать?

Comment: опубликуйте пожалуйста ваш файл `.ui`

Comment: @S.Nick, к сожалению не могу, секретные разработки;) А если честно, то там только сам виджет Tree и всё, ну и 2 столбца

Comment: я не прошу у вас  секретные разработки, нарисуйте виджет `Tree с двумя столбцами` и опубликуйте файл `.ui`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настораживает ваши скромность и нерешительность.

**treeW.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>573</width>
    <height>320</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTreeWidget" name="treeWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>554</width>
      <height>262</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
      <horstretch>58</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>554</width>
      <height>0</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="sizeIncrement">
     <size>
      <width>777</width>
      <height>0</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="baseSize">
     <size>
      <width>444</width>
      <height>3</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="palette">
     <palette>
      <active>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>213</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>191</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>63</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>85</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>113</red>
          <green>170</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="BrightText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Base">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Window">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Shadow">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>212</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>220</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </active>
      <inactive>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>213</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>191</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>63</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>85</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>113</red>
          <green>170</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="BrightText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Base">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Window">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Shadow">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>212</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>220</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </inactive>
      <disabled>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>85</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>213</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>127</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>191</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>63</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>85</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>113</red>
          <green>170</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>85</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="BrightText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>255</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>85</red>
          <green>127</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Base">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Window">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Shadow">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="AlternateBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>170</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipBase">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>255</red>
          <green>255</green>
          <blue>220</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ToolTipText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </disabled>
     </palette>
    </property>
    <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
     <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="autoScrollMargin">
     <number>30</number>
    </property>
    <property name="indentation">
     <number>17</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rootIsDecorated">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="animated">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="allColumnsShowFocus">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="wordWrap">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="headerHidden">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="expandsOnDoubleClick">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="columnCount">
     <number>3</number>
    </property>
    <attribute name="headerVisible">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="headerCascadingSectionResizes">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="headerDefaultSectionSize">
     <number>174</number>
    </attribute>
    <attribute name="headerHighlightSections">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </attribute>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Column 1</string>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>16</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Column 2</string>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>16</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>3</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Item 1</string>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>10</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
       <strikeout>false</strikeout>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Hello</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="flags">
      <set>ItemIsSelectable|ItemIsDragEnabled|ItemIsUserCheckable|ItemIsEnabled|ItemIsTristate</set>
     </property>
     <item>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Subitem 11</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>World</string>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <item>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Subitem 12</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </item>
     </item>
    </item>
    <item>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Item 2</string>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>10</pointsize>
       <weight>75</weight>
       <bold>true</bold>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string/>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>573</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простите что не отвечал, сегодня экзамен, готовился к нему. Спасибо вам огромное всё работает!